# What is the best way to perhaps call a function, every time, inside a class?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a class that has an **optional** function as a parameter. Sometimes I create instances of this class with a function, sometimes not.

The function is called every time when some methods of the instance are called. Of course if the function was not given, nothing happens there.

My question is, what is the best way to achieve this ? I tried a couple of things. Can you judge my solutions, by performance, scalability and readability ? Do you have better solutions ?

The class looks like this

```
class MyClass(...):
    def __init__(self, function=None):
        self.function = function

    def method_a(self, ...)
        ...
        self.function(a,b,c)
        ...

    def method_b(self, ...)
        ...
        self.function(a,b,c)
        ...

    def method_c(self, ...)
        ...
        #not every method bothers with the function
        ...
```

Of course this produces

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

The most naive solution is to change the class itself with defensive ifs or trials:

```
class MyClass(...):
    def __init__(self, function=None):
        self.function = function

    def method_a(self, ...)
        ...
        if self.function:
            self.function(a,b,c)
        ...

    def method_b(self, ...)
        ...
        if self.function:
            self.function(a,b,c)
        ...
```

second solution is to create a do nothing function and perhaps store it in `self.function`:

```
def do_nothing(*x):
    pass

class MyClass(...):
    def __init__(self, function=None):
        if function is None:
            function = do_nothing
        self.function = function

    def method_a(self, ...)
        ...
        self.function(a,b,c)
        ...

    def method_b(self, ...)
        ...
        self.function(a,b,c)
        ...
```

the third solution is to create a function wrapper with defensive ifs inside it:

```
class Maybe(object):
    def __init__(self, function=None):
        self.function = function

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if self.function is None:
            return
        # else
        return self.function(args)

class MyClass(...):
    def __init__(self, function=None):
        self.function = Maybe(function)

    def method_a(self, ...)
        ...
        self.function(a,b,c)
        ...

    def method_b(self, ...)
        ...
        self.function(a,b,c)
        ...
```

Comment: I'd say, the second one. Just add a default argument: `__init__(self, function=lambda *x: None)`.

Comment: @georg, it doesn't scale well. In my example I have 1 conditional function that doesn't mean, that I have 1 in my program.

Comment: You have to be more specific then. What is the actual problem you're working on? Without knowing all the details we can only speculate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone will tell you that performance shouldn't influence your code design unless you find a bottleneck and can measure it. What matters though, is code readability.

Adding a `if` condition before each call is readable but repetitive. Repetitive tasks are usually wrapped into a simple function, so why not doing that?

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, function=None):
        self._function = function

    def method(self):
        self._callFunction("Charlie")

    def _callFunction(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._function:
            self._function(*args, **kwargs)

def myFunction(name):
    print("Je suis %s" % name)

instance = MyClass(myFunction)
instance.method()
```

Comment: It does not scale very well, I can't imagine myself writing an additional method for each conditional function.

Comment: You don't mention any such thing in your question. And I'm actually not sure to understand what you are after then? The class `MyClass` from my answer can take any function that you might decide to pass, and thus with any combination of arguments possible—isn't it what you were looking for? In which way is it supposed to scale? Do you want to have a you class `MyClass` to contain more than a single method?